# Bubblewrap build fails, FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity, bubblewrap

The error below is part of what it spits out when I tried to run the command `bubblewrap build`
. The website was built with reactjs and I'm using windows 10.
I've gone through some of the similar problems posted and answered here, but they mostly seem to be related to cordova, and nothing seemed to work for me.
It is safe to say that I don't know what I'm doing with bubblewrap, this will be my first use of it. What I'm I missing pls.

ERROR Command failed: gradlew.bat assembleRelease --stacktrace

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Could not create task ':app:minifyReleaseWithR8'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskDependencyResolveException: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:packageRelease'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:69)

Answer (score 2):

When using babblewrap, I also experienced many problems. Several important points to be successful. that is:

- install jdk and android sdk from default/recommended bubblewrap (even if you already have it before)
- in env, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` use `jdk 8`
- in the gradle.properties file, change `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m`

good luck. happy to share. :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who faces this same problem with bubblewrap, I found the solution and what I did was to delete the .gradle file in  "C:\Users\Administrator".
I got this by following a similar issue in flutter from the github page https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/69845